# An exception of type System.InvalidCastException while casting to a List<>

Tags: c#, json

I am retrieving Json data from a service and I try to do this afterwards but this exception gets thrown. with this details 
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sample.Reply]'.
 does anyone know what am getting wrong.

```
private List<Reply> CreateListFromJson(Stream stream)
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Reply>));
        var replies = (List<Reply>)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        return replies;
    }
```

The reply class is defined as this

```
public class Reply
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic { get; set; }
}
```

and this is what the Json looks like

```
{
"status": "OK",
"Error": "None",
"Reason": "successful",
"details": {
    "replies": [
        {
            "comment": "great",
            "username": "Crimson Kajes",
            "profile_pic": "http://ibotv.iboapis.com/profile/20130506_044930.jpg"
        },
        {
            "comment": "great",
            "username": "Crimson Kajes",
            "profile_pic": "http://ibotv.iboapis.com/profile/20130506_044930.jpg"
        },
        {
            "comment": "wonderful",
            "username": "Crimson Kajes",
            "profile_pic": "http://ibotv.iboapis.com/profile/20130506_044930.jpg"
        },
        {
            "comment": "wow",
            "username": "Crimson Kajes",
            "profile_pic": "http://ibotv.iboapis.com/profile/20130506_044930.jpg"
        },
        {
            "comment": "thank God",
            "username": "Crimson Kajes",
            "profile_pic": "http://ibotv.iboapis.com/profile/20130506_044930.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "totalreply": "5"
}
```

}

Comment: And you think your json is unrelated to your question therefore didn't post it.

Comment: I have added how the Json data look like

Comment: Did you look at what `ReadObject` returns *without* the cast? Pretty sure you are getting more than just a list of `Reply` (in other words: take a look at what the object is in the debugger before casting... it can tell you a lot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your `Reply` class only represents the objects in *replies* property. Your model should be something like this:

```
public class Reply
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public List<Reply> replies { get; set; }
    public string totalreply { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public Details details { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
var root = (RootObject)ser.ReadObject(stream);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is right I tried typeofRootObject but still the same exception. Please how do I pass the return into a JsonObject and the replies to JsonArrays then make it a list that can be bound to. I think that's what I need to do but don't know how to do it

Comment: @OmotayoJacob  I posted it after testing your json with the model above. I don't know what you are doing but above code is completely correct. (BTW: There is no way to get the same exception. How about copying  the code from here?)

Comment: Yeah, it's correct but how do I get a list of replies because in my question the CreateListFromJson(Stream stream) has to return a List<> type, how do I do that

Comment: It worked, thanks, but i'm not dumb, I am just a beginner

Comment: @OmotayoJacob I know, sorry.  But use VS and its debugger to help you. You just comment without trying anything or thinking about the new model. This is why I complained.

Comment: there are more issues am facing in the project, can I ask?

Comment: @OmotayoJacob Every question on SO should cover one topic. Feel free to ask new questions.